# Possible to set value in @html.label using jquery in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a   `@Html.Label("", new { id="txtStatus1" })`

where txtstatus1 value is obtained using jquery as 
        `$('#txtStatus1').val(TicketStatus);`

but im not able to set this value to label .

Comment: try `.text()` instead of `.val()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This statement does not output anything as you have not specified a for value:

```
@Html.Label("", new { id="txtStatus1" })
```

If you change it to give it a value i.e.

```
@Html.Label("a", new { id="txtStatus1" })
```

It outputs this:

```
<label for="a" id="txtStatus1">a</label>
```

Sridhar R is correct you can use text to set it like this:

```
$('#txtStatus1').text('this')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bk8KZ/

You might need to add quotes and output around the argument if it is comming from your model i.e.

```
$('#txtStatus1').val('@Model.TicketStatus');
```

What is TicketStatus exactly?

Comment: ticketstaus is a variable to set value.I solved the problem by using <p id="qqq"> where $('#qqq').text(variable);

Answer (score 5):

Try this

Use `.text()` or `.html()`

Get html label value

```
var txt = $('#lbltxt').html();
```

Set html label value

```
$('#lbltxt').html("your value");
```

To get asp.net label value we need to write the code like as shown below

```
var txt = $('#<%=lbltxt.ClientID%>').html();
```

or

```
var txt = $("[id$='lbltxt']").html()
```

Set Asp.net label Value

```
$('#<%= lbltxt.ClientID%>').html('Your Value')
```

Or

```
$("[id$=' lbltxt']").html('Your Value')
```

Comment: I'm using html5 and MVC4 RAZOR setting query as 
        $('#txtStatus1').text(TicketStatus);  did not help !!